# ASP.Net MVC, How to set an image from an action link as <div> background?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an image from an Url.Action, like this

```
<img src="<%= Url.Action("Image") %>" alt="" />
```

How can I set this image as a background to a div? I tried this:

```
<div style="background-image:url(/Background/Image)"></div>
```

and others, but no success, I'm trying to play with JS over that div, and I need that background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Url.Content.  I was recently trying to do the same thing for my JavaScript files and I found out about Url.Content from [this blog](http://lancefisher.net/blog/archive/2008/03/16/referencing-javascript-in-asp.net-mvc-master-pages.aspx).

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/packed.js") %>"></script>
```

For your DIV, I'd do (shortened for readability):

```
<div style="background-image:url(<%= Url.Content("~/Bkd/img.jpg") %>)"></div>
```

Comment: Thank You! Problem solved:

<div id="canvas" style="background-image:url(<%= Url.Content("~/Background/Image") %>)"> </div>